# Generic List XML Serialization with different classes

Tags: c#, generics, xml-serialization, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5

I have got the following code:

**BaseContent.cs**

```
public class BaseContent
{
   // Some auto properties
}
```

**News.cs**

```
public class News : BaseContent
{
   // Some more auto properties
}
```

**Events.cs**

```
public class Event : BaseContent
{
   // Some more auto properites
}
```

**GenericResponse.cs**

```
public class GenericResponse<T> 
{
  [XmlArray("Content")]
  [XmlArrayItem("NewsObject", typeof(News)]
  [XmlArrayItem("EventObject", typeof(Event)]
  public List<T> ContentItems { get; set; }
}
```

**NewsResponse.cs**

```
public class NewsResponse : GenericResponse<News> {}
```

**EventResponse.cs**

```
public class EventResponse : GenericResponse<Event> {}
```

As you can see, I have a base class **BaseContent** and two classes deriving from it. Next I have a generic response class, since the structure of the xml-files is always the same, but they differ in some properties.

I thought I can specify with the `[XmlArrayItem]` which name to use for a specific class. But now I get the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
>   error CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I can not add this reference, because I'm working on a Windows 8 App.

If I comment out one of the `[XmlArrayItem]` it is working well.

Anyone got an idea to solve this problem?

**Update**
I can **not** use DataContractSerializer, because I **have to** use XmlAttributes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit: Feel free to download the [demo project](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B411XiA1vaSzMmgyNnA0SjFYVWM)

You didn't provide all the properties for the objects, so allow me to add some - just as an example:

```
public class BaseContent
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlType(TypeName = "EventObject")]
public class Event : BaseContent
{
    [XmlAttribute("EventId")]
    public int EventId { get; set; }
}

[XmlType(TypeName = "NewsObject")]
public class News : BaseContent
{
    [XmlAttribute("NewsId")]
    public int NewsId { get; set; }
}
```

GenericResponse.cs could be defined this way - no need to specify the typeof for the array items:

```
public class GenericResponse<T>
{
    [XmlArray("Content")]
    public List<T> ContentItems { get; set; }

    public GenericResponse()
    {
        this.ContentItems = new List<T>();
    }
}
```

And then you have the response classes:

```
public class EventResponse : GenericResponse<Event>
{
}

public class NewsResponse : GenericResponse<News>
{
}
```

## Example 1: Serialize an EventResponse object

```
var response = new EventResponse
{
    ContentItems = new List<Event> 
    {
        new Event {
            EventId = 1,
            Name = "Event 1"
        },

        new Event {
            EventId = 2,
            Name = "Event 2"
        }
    }
};

string xml = XmlSerializer<EventResponse>.Serialize(response);
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EventResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Content>
        <EventObject Name="Event 1" EventId="1" />
        <EventObject Name="Event 2" EventId="2" />
    </Content>
</EventResponse>
```

If you try the same with NewsResponse it will work fine. BTW I'm using my [generic XmlSerializer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233908/Xml-serialization-using-generics), click on the link to know more about it.

XmlSerializer.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// XML serializer helper class. Serializes and deserializes objects from/to XML
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the object to serialize/deserialize.
/// Must have a parameterless constructor and implement <see cref="Serializable"/></typeparam>
public class XmlSerializer<T> where T: class, new()
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes a XML string into an object
    /// Default encoding: <c>UTF8</c>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml">The XML string to deserialize</param>
    /// <returns>An object of type <c>T</c></returns>
    public static T Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        return Deserialize(xml, Encoding.UTF8, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes a XML string into an object
    /// Default encoding: <c>UTF8</c>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml">The XML string to deserialize</param>
    /// <param name="encoding">The encoding</param>
    /// <returns>An object of type <c>T</c></returns>
    public static T Deserialize(string xml, Encoding encoding)
    {
        return Deserialize(xml, encoding, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes a XML string into an object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml">The XML string to deserialize</param>
    /// <param name="settings">XML serialization settings. <see cref="System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings"/></param>
    /// <returns>An object of type <c>T</c></returns>
    public static T Deserialize(string xml, XmlReaderSettings settings)
    {
        return Deserialize(xml, Encoding.UTF8, settings);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes a XML string into an object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml">The XML string to deserialize</param>
    /// <param name="encoding">The encoding</param>
    /// <param name="settings">XML serialization settings. <see cref="System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings"/></param>
    /// <returns>An object of type <c>T</c></returns>
    public static T Deserialize(string xml, Encoding encoding, XmlReaderSettings settings)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
            throw new ArgumentException("XML cannot be null or empty", "xml");

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(xml)))
        {
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(memoryStream, settings))
            {
                return (T) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes a XML file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">The filename of the XML file to deserialize</param>
    /// <returns>An object of type <c>T</c></returns>
    public static T DeserializeFromFile(string filename)
    {
        return DeserializeFromFile(filename, new XmlReaderSettings());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes a XML file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">The filename of the XML file to deserialize</param>
    /// <param name="settings">XML serialization settings. <see cref="System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings"/></param>
    /// <returns>An object of type <c>T</c></returns>
    public static T DeserializeFromFile(string filename, XmlReaderSettings settings)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            throw new ArgumentException("filename", "XML filename cannot be null or empty");

        if (! File.Exists(filename))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot find XML file to deserialize", filename);

        // Create the stream writer with the specified encoding
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filename, settings))
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize an object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The object to serialize</param>
    /// <returns>A XML string that represents the object to be serialized</returns>
    public static string Serialize(T source)
    {
        // indented XML by default
        return Serialize(source, null, GetIndentedSettings());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize an object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The object to serialize</param>
    /// <param name="namespaces">Namespaces to include in serialization</param>
    /// <returns>A XML string that represents the object to be serialized</returns>
    public static string Serialize(T source, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
    {
        // indented XML by default
        return Serialize(source, namespaces, GetIndentedSettings());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize an object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The object to serialize</param>
    /// <param name="settings">XML serialization settings. <see cref="System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings"/></param>
    /// <returns>A XML string that represents the object to be serialized</returns>
    public static string Serialize(T source, XmlWriterSettings settings)
    {
        return Serialize(source, null, settings);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize an object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The object to serialize</param>
    /// <param name="namespaces">Namespaces to include in serialization</param>
    /// <param name="settings">XML serialization settings. <see cref="System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings"/></param>
    /// <returns>A XML string that represents the object to be serialized</returns>
    public static string Serialize(T source, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, XmlWriterSettings settings)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source", "Object to serialize cannot be null");

        string xml = null;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(source.GetType());

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, settings))
            {
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                x.Serialize(xmlWriter, source, namespaces);

                memoryStream.Position = 0; // rewind the stream before reading back.
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
                {
                    xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
                } 
            }
        }

        return xml;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize an object to a XML file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The object to serialize</param>
    /// <param name="filename">The file to generate</param>
    public static void SerializeToFile(T source, string filename)
    {
        // indented XML by default
        SerializeToFile(source, filename, null, GetIndentedSettings());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize an object to a XML file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The object to serialize</param>
    /// <param name="filename">The file to generate</param>
    /// <param name="namespaces">Namespaces to include in serialization</param>
    public static void SerializeToFile(T source, string filename, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
    {
        // indented XML by default
        SerializeToFile(source, filename, namespaces, GetIndentedSettings());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize an object to a XML file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The object to serialize</param>
    /// <param name="filename">The file to generate</param>
    /// <param name="settings">XML serialization settings. <see cref="System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings"/></param>
    public static void SerializeToFile(T source, string filename, XmlWriterSettings settings)
    {
         SerializeToFile(source, filename, null, settings);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize an object to a XML file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The object to serialize</param>
    /// <param name="filename">The file to generate</param>
    /// <param name="namespaces">Namespaces to include in serialization</param>
    /// <param name="settings">XML serialization settings. <see cref="System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings"/></param>
    public static void SerializeToFile(T source, string filename, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, XmlWriterSettings settings)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source", "Object to serialize cannot be null");

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(source.GetType());

        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filename, settings))
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            x.Serialize(xmlWriter, source, namespaces);
        }
    }

    #region Private methods


    private static XmlWriterSettings GetIndentedSettings()
    {
        XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
        xmlWriterSettings.IndentChars = "\t";

        return xmlWriterSettings;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Really nice answer, but currently not exactly what I need. In your case the XML will be <Item EventId="..."/> and so on. This will not work for me. In case of the events I need EventObject, in case of news I need NewsObject. I tried to do this by adding [XmlType("EventObject")] to your event-class, but didn't help either. Well, the easiest thing for me would be to rename my class "event" to "EventObject" and remove the [XmlArrayItem]-Attribute. But I don't like the naming of object to be "*Object".

Comment: @Raubi: That's just an example, you can customise the XML the way you want. I cannot give you a better answer because I don't know what XML output you want. Please edit your answer and include the expected XML output for your classes.

Comment: @Raubi: Edited my answer. I'm not sure if the XML is exactly what you need, but I think that you'll find all that you need to customise your XML in my answer. Feel free to download the demo project, the link is in the top. PS: Happy new year!

Comment: Now it es exactly what I need :-) I thought I tried this one, but maybe I didn't. It's working like a charm. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I found my solution. No the best, but it is working.

I impleted IXmlSerializable and handeled the stuff by myself:

```
public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
{
    reader.Read();
    reader.MoveToContent();

    if (reader.LocalName == "AnotherNode")
    {
        var innerXml = Serializer<AnotherClass>.CreateSerializer();
        Remove = (AnotherClass) innerXml.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.MoveToContent();
    }

    reader.Read();

    // Here is the trick
    if (reader.IsStartElement())
    {
        do
        {
            var innerXml = Serializer<T>.CreateSerializer();

            var obj = (T) innerXml.Deserialize(reader);
            Updates.Add(obj);
        } while (reader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element);
    }
}

public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
{
    var removeSerializer = Serializer<RemoveElement>.CreateSerializer();
    removeSerializer.Serialize(writer, Remove);

    if (Updates.Any())
    {
        var innerXml = Serializer<T>.CreateSerializer();
        writer.WriteStartElement("ContentUpdates");
        foreach (var update in Updates)
        {
            innerXml.Serialize(writer, update);
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using DataContractSerializer instead of XmlSerializer.

XmlSerializer is generating at runtime a temp assembly, in order to speed up
serialization - deserialization  process later on. Thus it requires code compilation.

DataContractSerializer on the other hand does not. In case you use the DataContractSerializer
approach you have to play around with appropriate attributes, so that you control "inheritence"
issues.

Comment: Sorry, DataContractSerializer is not possible. I need to have XmlAttributes

Answer (score 0):

That *sounds* like a bug in the code-emitter for `XmlSerializer` for the Windows Store platform specifically, but it is a bit moot, because it still fails on regular .NET, but with a different message:

> Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
>
> error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'News' to 'Event'
>
> error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(News)' has some invalid arguments
>
> error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Event' to 'News'

So basically, it looks like an unsupported scenario that manifests differently in the two scenarios. Fundamentally, the issue is that you're annotations are saying (for `T`=`News`) "if this `News` is a `News`, call the element 'NewsObject'; if this `News` is an `Event`, call the element 'EventObject'" - which is odd because a `News` is **never** an `Event`, etc.

However, the good news is that what you want to do can be done just using `[XmlType(...)]`:

```
[XmlType("NewsObject")]
public class News : BaseContent
{
    // Some more auto properties
    public int B { get; set; }
}
[XmlType("EventObject")]
public class Event : BaseContent
{
    // Some more auto properites
    public int C { get; set; }
}
...
public class GenericResponse<T>
{
    [XmlArray("Content")]
    public List<T> ContentItems { get; set; }
}
```

note: no `[XmlArrayItem(...)]` in the above.

which then outputs (after formatting, cleaning, etc):

```
<NewsResponse>
    <Content>
        <NewsObject><A>1</A><B>2</B></NewsObject>
    </Content>
</NewsResponse>
```

via the test code:

```
var obj = new NewsResponse { ContentItems = new List<News> {
    new News { A = 1, B = 2 } } };

var sw = new StringWriter();
using (var xw = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sw))
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
    ser.Serialize(xw, obj);
}
string xml = sw.ToString();
```

If you need more control than that, then `XmlAttributeOverrides` is the thing to look at; but you **must** cache serializers created with `XmlAttributeOverrides`, to avoid hemorrhaging assemblies and getting a memory leak.